# Oauth Account Manager return error credentials

Tags: java, android, authentication, google-plus, accountmanager

As I'm using oauth2.0 to get the user details it is working correct and giving correct credentials in android above 4.0 version.But when coming to android 2.3.6 it returning the following error credentials.As I'm using scope

> public static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";

.But at some time working fine when I'm signing with new account and next time when I'm choosing account from account chooser it returning the following

```
{
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
       }
      ],
      "code": 401,
      "message": "Invalid Credentials"
     }
    }
```

As i verified this credentials with following url

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token={"our access token"}